# Author Tools layout for a table of contents

Tags: front-end, notebooks, stylesheet

Can someone point me at the place, where the Layout of the Table of Contents is stored in the Author Tools. There should be some style sheet, but I can't find it.

Author Tools is still a very useful package even though WRI has abandoned all support for authoring in *Mathematica*.

There is a command

```
StyleBox["\t", "Leader"]
```

in the TOC in cells named TOCPage, TOCS[ubs]ection which produces dots between say Section-Title and the pagenumber.
I want to just set the tabstop a little differently.
The option `TabSpacings` works only on Text-Cells.

But also I want to change other layout items.

Comment: Many thanks. I'll look for it soon. How did you know that? I generate a TOC from 6 notebooks with overall about 100 pages, but after about 50 pages the page count breaks in the TOC. Do you have experience with the Author Tools? I use mathematica 9. Many thanks again.

Comment: I have discovered this in 2006 (!). I remember it was difficult to obtain this information. I probably did with the windows explorer  a "search everywhere" a file "*.nb" containing "AuthorTools" or may be "bilateralcell". After  Mma 5, AuthorTools is nearly no usable, despite some informations that let think It could be. I have tried to do my own AuthorTools but I gave up. I don't remember exactly what were the difficulties. (Pagination of the whole notebook by the frontend ? retrieving the page number of cells with a certain CellTag ? ...)

Comment: The difficulties I encoutered was with small notebooks. I have never tried with large notebooks. I seems that there are other difficulties in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The styles of the AuthorTools are in the stylesheet "HelpBrowser.nb"

`FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
  "StyleSheets", "HelpBrowser.nb"}]`

For me, it gives :

> "C:\Program Files\Wolfram \
>   Research\Mathematica\10.0\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\StyleSheets\\
>   HelpBrowser.nb"

`FileNameJoin[]` exists since Mathematica 7. If you have an earlier version of Mathematica you can reconstruct the path yourself.

Comment: Pre-7 there was [`ToFileName`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToFileName.html)